# Some javascript automatically add to my website

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap. I found that at the very end of my website, there are some javascript add to my website and I am not the one add it.

[The website is this](http://dive.abi.org)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beacon-5.newrelic.com/1/cc4ac3cc4f?a=2052446&amp;be=180&amp;qt=0&amp;ap=0&amp;dc=222&amp;fe=346&amp;to=ZVMGZxMCXxdTUBVfXFwZMUEITFgKVlYZGENaRg%3D%3D&amp;v=42&amp;jsonp=NREUM.setToken&amp;perf=%7B%22timing%22%3A%7B%22of%22%3A1393884062798%2C%20%22n%22%3A0%2C%20%22u%22%3A95%2C%20%22ue%22%3A95%2C%20%22dl%22%3A103%2C%20%22di%22%3A402%2C%20%22ds%22%3A402%2C%20%22de%22%3A429%2C%20%22dc%22%3A524%2C%20%22l%22%3A524%2C%20%22le%22%3A527%2C%20%22f%22%3A0%2C%20%22dn%22%3A0%2C%20%22dne%22%3A0%2C%20%22c%22%3A0%2C%20%22ce%22%3A0%2C%20%22rq%22%3A4%2C%20%22rp%22%3A93%2C%20%22rpe%22%3A94%7D%2C%20%22navigation%22%3A%7B%22ty%22%3A1%7D%7D"></script>
```

I only have these four js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using a free hosting?

Comment: Dreamhost. http://www.whoishostingthis.com/dive.abi.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from [New Relic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work) monitoring services. Either one of your site templates or your hosting provider injects the code there.